# Python numpy.load mmap_mode overwrites original data - bug?

Tags: python, numpy

So it seems I don't understand how np.load(..., mmap_mode = 'r+') works. It seems that whenever I load such a file from disk into a variable and change some values in that variable it overwrites the data on the disk.  This is not what I expected, and it seems like a bug to me.

Here's my code:

```
#Load original image data    
original_image = np.load(filename, mmap_mode='r+')

#change a single pixel
original_image[0,45,8] = 0.10

#The raw data on the disk has now been overwritten by the statement above
```

Does this sound right? It doesn't appear to be just a matter of cached memory because I loaded the data using a different program and it seems the raw data was overwritten.

Any help or suggestions? Is this expected behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: *"Is this expected behaviour?"*  Yes.  Read the [docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html).  For the `mmap_mode` argument, it directs you to [`numpy.memmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html), where you can find the answer.  (Maybe you want `mmap_mode='c'`? Do you even want the data to be memory-mapped?  If not, don't specify the `mmap_mode` argument.  The default behavior is to copy the data into memory.)

Comment: Thanks, that seems correct. I didn't realize that 'r+' flag could mean write, let alone write to disk? That's pretty unexpected from my end as simple np.load() does not affect data on disk. Thanksfully I didn't destroy too much of my data. Cheers.